# XMLHttpRequest not wokirng for specific URL?

Tags: javascript

```js
var xhr1 = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr1.onload = function() {
    FeHelper.filterFetchData(this.responseXML.body);
}
xhr1.open('GET', 'https://www.alansfactoryoutlet.com/', true); //Working
xhr1.responseType = "document";
xhr1.send();


var xhr2 = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr2.onload = function() {
    FeHelper.filterFetchData(this.responseXML.body);
}
xhr2.open('GET', 'https://store.alansfactoryoutlet.com/', true); //Not Working
xhr2.responseType = "document";
xhr2.send();
```

The first part of fetching data working nicely but the second part not working.Shows

`VM3210:1 GET https://store.alansfactoryoutlet.com/ net::ERR_FAILED` error.

Comment: If the web page is in `www.alansfactoryoutlet.com`, the second one fails the same-domain restriction. Are you getting a CORS error in the console?

Comment: Yeah this says cors error

Comment: Then on the second request, the server is rejecting your request because it has probably been configured to if you're requesting the document on a different domain

Comment: If this is code you have control over, the scripts on `store` can allow requests from `www` by sending an appropriate `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header. Read up on cross-domain AAJX.